# SizeChanged Event Isn't Firing

Tags: c#, wpf, resize, screen-resolution

So, I've been researching the `SizeChanged` event recently because I want my font size to scale proportionally, and though I have searched through many posts, none of them are working for me - my object isn't firing.

Here's my code:

```
private void MainWindow_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) {
    welcomeTitleText.Text = "hi";
}
```

This doesn't even use like the window size, it just changes the text, to make sure it's firing. However, it's not working for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you assign it in xaml also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you are subscribing to the event. You have to register the handler for the event, either in code or in xaml.

In Code example:

```
public MainWindow()
{

    // This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent();

    // Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    this.SizeChanged += MainWindow_SizeChanged;
}
```

or in xaml:

```
<Window     
    x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"        
        mc:Ignorable="d"
    ...
    Loaded="AboutWindow_Loaded">
...
```

Also note that some times the sizeChanged event does not fire if wpf's backend thinks the change is too insignificant. [See the docs for more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.sizechanged?view=netframework-4.7.1#remarks).

A Tip, you might try wrapping your Text in a Viewbox, this will autosize it to the maximum fill size. Then you can just limit the size (i.e. maxwidth, maxheight) of the view box (or it's container (i'd recommend using a grid, and seeing column & row height using * (stars) or pt, [more details here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.gridlength?view=netframework-4.7.1)) to achieve reasonable scaling. E.g:

```
<Viewbox MaxHeight="50">
    <TextBlock>I'm Scaled Text</TextBlock>
</Viewbox>
```